# DataTable's Row's First Column to String Array

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTable. I want to get every rows first column value and append to a string array. I  do not want to use foreach  looping for every row and adding to string array. I tried this, but stuck at some point

```
DataRow[] dr = new DataRow[dtCampaignSubscriberLists.Rows.Count];
dtCampaignSubscriberLists.Rows.CopyTo(dr, 0);
string[] array = Array.ConvertAll(dr, new Converter<DataRow, String>(????));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
string[] array = yourTable
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(row => row.Field<string>("ColumnName"))
                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Alot, i guess you forgot parantheses after .AsEnumarable

Comment: @Yagiz, indeed, I did. Was typing it directly in. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

`dtCampaignSubscriberLists.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[0].ToString()).ToArray();`

Comment: I was going to pick the selected comment code but then i was too lazy to check the column's name in the database so im going with this one :D